# Characterization of the convex hull in terms of dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

I am doing some work with Newton Polytopes and I need something of this style:

> Given $v_1,\dots,v_n\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
>
> $$\text{conv}(v_1,\dots v_n)=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid \min_{i=1,\dots n}\{x\cdot v_i\}\leq x\cdot v \;\;\forall \, x\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$$

As the condition defining the set in the left is true for the $v_i$ and is closed under convex combinations then $\subseteq$ is easy. My problem is to show that

> $$\min_{i=1,\dots n}\{x\cdot v_i\}\leq x\cdot v \;\;\forall \, x\in \mathbb{R}^n\implies v\in \text{conv}(v_1,\dots v_n)$$

This is trivial for $n=1$ but I can't see it for all $n$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If v wasn't in the convex hull, you could construct an affine function f so that f(v) < 0, while $f(v_i) \geq 0$. (Hyperplane separation theorem.)

Comment: It was really easy thinking in that way. Thanks!
You can put the hint as an answer if you want.